# What live tile template does the official calendar app use in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to use a live tile layout similar to the official Windows Phone 8 "Calendar" app for my app's live tile and I am also trying to update the lock screen notification. I was originally planning on using the Iconic tile template because it seems to be the most straightforward means to display text, but realized that it does not display any text unless the user uses the wide tile size. The other option seems to be flip tile, but I want the text to be displayed on the front of the tile, not on the flip side. I considered using the cycle tile template and generate the image to show for various tile sizes, but seems like I can't update the lock screen notification if I use that. Does anyone know how I can display text on a medium sized tile and also have the same text appear on the lock screen notification?

Answer (score 0):

It does not use a publicly available tile template. You would have to recreate the template using an image, for example as in http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/05/wp8-tip-creating-live-tiles-with.html